# Stubbing non-exported function with sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, sinon, stub

I write a unit-test for `doB` function of my module.

I want to stub the function `doA` **without** exporting it, I prefer not change the way `doB` accesses `doA`.

I understand that it cannot be simply `stub`ed because it isnt in the exported object.

How do I stub `doA` (`sinon` or any other tool?)

```
function doA (value) {
   /* do stuff */
}

function doB (value) {
  let resultA = doA(value);
  if (resultA === 'something') {
     /* do some */
  } else {
     /* do otherwise */
  }
}

module.exports = exports = {
   doB
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I did it using rewire too. This is what I came up with

```
const demographic = rewire('./demographic')

const getDemographicsObject = { getDemographics: demographic.__get__('getDemographics') };

const stubGetDemographics = sinon
 .stub(getDemographicsObject, 'getDemographics')
 .returns(testScores);

demographic.__set__('getDemographics', stubGetDemographics);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it says _get_  is not a function do we have to have any specific js version in order to use this function?

Comment: Are you using rewire to import the module?  did you check examples here: https://github.com/jhnns/rewire ?

Comment: yes it is working now i was doing it wrong. Thanks for the help

Comment: In the snippet, I think `reqire` should be `rewire`

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up using [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire), I can either just `__get__` an internal function from the module and the `stub` it with `sinon` or use`rewire`'s  `__with__` utility to invoke a function with replaced internal values

Comment: hi I am trying the same approach.. with not much luck, are you able to share a snippet of what you have done?

Comment: @mikey I afraid I don't have access to the code anymore :(

Comment: all good! I made it somehow, maybe I'll post my answer here!! thank you anyway @agoldis

Comment: @mikey, can you please share stub of non-exported function?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you don't care about fetching the original function, but rather just want to stub it, the first part is unnecessary. You can do something like this instead:

```js
function stubPrivateMethod(modulePath, methodName) {
    const module = rewire(modulePath);
    
    const stub = sinon.stub();

    module.__set__(methodName, stub);

    return stub;
}
```